# Count of repeated persian words in columns with python

Tags: python, nan, farsi

#### What I have:

I have a DataFrame (`df`) with 2 columns.

In `df["Words"]` I have some Persian\Farsi words.

| Words | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| سلام |  |
| کشور زیبا ؟ |  |
| 28 % ایران |  |
| ایران طلا |  |
| طلا ایران |  |
| سلام ایران |  |

#### What I would:

I would separate the words and count the frequency of every single word in column "Words":

| Words | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| سلام | 2 |
| کشور | 1 |
| زیبا | 1 |
| ؟ | 1 |
| ایران | 4 |
| طلا | 2 |
| % | 1 |

#### What I did:

```
df.Words.str.get_dummies(sep=' ').mul(df['count'], axis=0).sum()
```

#### What I received from python :

| Words | Counts |
| --- | --- |
| سلام | NAN |
| کشور | NAN |
| زیبا | NAN |
| ؟ | NAN |
| ایران | NAN |
| طلا | NAN |
| % | NAN |

The problem is the formatting or the code?

Answer (score 1):

This handles " " and "." (at the end of a sentence). I am not sure if there are any othere separators in farsi. If you need to add them, just add them to the "separators" string.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

separators = ". "
df = pd.DataFrame({"Words": ["hi you there", "hello all"]})

def get_word_len(words: str) -> int:
   return len(re.split(separators, words))

df["Counts"] = df.Words.apply(get_word_len)

print(df)
```

Thank you for your feedback. I understood the task a little bit wrong. This should solve your problem. (of course df should be replaced with your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Words": ["hi you there", "hello all hi"]})

words = list()
for word in df["Words"]:
    words = words + word.split(" ")

df_a = pd.DataFrame({"words": words})
print(df_a["words"].value_counts())
```

result:

```
hi       2
there    1
all      1
hello    1
you      1
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not what I want. I would, that the code: 1- Separate the word. -->2-Count the Words/Symbols --> 3- Show me how many is the count of each Word\Symbol